# How to open file explorer to open import workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the below code in VBA for Excel.

My intention was to go fetch a workbook from the file explorer and open the wokbook to import or copy data from. The file explorer is opening, but the copy and pasting is not happening.

The debugger tells me the problem is in line 13 with the range.copy code (It tells me: subscript out of range), but I tried it on its own in a different module and it works, so I have the feeling the problem actually lies in line 11.

Anyone have a clue?

To be clear, the file to import from is always different, which is why I want to select it from the file explorer every time

```
Sub ImportData()
Dim FileLocation As String
    
FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename
If FileLocation = "False" Then
Beep
Exit Sub
End If
   
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ImportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation)
   
ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("F11:Q18").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis (blk sub)").Range("B14:M21")
    
ImportWorkbook.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The error means that either the opened workbook doesn't have two sheets, or the destination sheet doesn't exist in the code workbook.

Comment: Does the opened workbook have more than one workheet?

Comment: Hi @Shrotter yes, both the source and destination workbooks have more than one sheet. I want to copy from the 2nd worksheet of the source into the one called ""Analysis (blk sub)" of the destination

Comment: Hi @Rory both the source and destination workbooks have more than one sheet. I want to copy from the 2nd worksheet of the source into the one called ""Analysis (blk sub)" of the destination

Comment: In that case either that sheet name is wrong, or it's not in the workbook where the code is.

Comment: Hi @Rory, the sheet names are correct, checked and re-checked. What I was trying to say is that I believe that the line above is the actual problem (Set ImportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation) despite what the debugger says, because the copy and paste line works just fine as a standalone code.

Comment: You could not get that error on that line.

Comment: @Rory, could you please help me write a code that would work for my purpose?

Comment: The code you have is fine. The only way you get a subscript out of range error is if the destination sheet name is wrong (eg a leading/trailing space), the destination sheet name is correct but it's not in the workbook with the code, or the opened workbook does not have two worksheets. Or perhaps the workbook you are opening has code in it that runs, and the error is there.